# How to count rows with filter in Hbase?

Tags: hbase

I need to find out only the row count of the result in a scan. The problem with the code below is that it returns the row key and the column key, which makes it very slow when shipping the data to the client. I only need to send the row count from the scan result to the client. Is there a specific way to do this directly?

```
scan 'consumer-data', {FILTER => "
PrefixFilter('test_row') 
AND KeyOnlyFilter() 
AND FirstKeyOnlyFilter() 
AND ((ColumnPrefixFilter('test_col:test1') 
AND ValueFilter(=, 'binary:test 1')) 
"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote is very very slow. First off scan works sequentially (no map/reduce) so that is slow to begin with. Then you use two slow filters one that looks at column names that and the worse filter that actually looks at values. - what you get is one by one sequential read that examines each each column and value for matching columns)

If you expect to run queries like these on a regular basis you should rethink your key. Also re do this as a map/reduce job, so at least it will divide the work

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option that i have used is **to create a HIVE table on Hbase and then query the HIve table instead using HQL (you can add where clause and all sort of conditions)**... this would internally automatically create a MapReduce Job for you and would run in cluster, so you don't have to worry about running multi threading and writing MR code.

Example below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE emp(id int, city string, name string, occupation string, salary int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,
                   personal_data:city,
                   personal_data:name,
                   professional_data:occupation,
                   professional_data:salary")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "emp");

Select count(*) from emp where city = 'LA';
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I would like to give you 2 options.

1. Use MapReduce jobs.  You should write your own MR jobs to actually run the counting job throughout the cluster.
2. Use multi-threading.  You can write multi-threading scan tasks to count with filters on hbase regions.  For example: 1 thread per region to do the counting.

Just for your reference: I have tried both strategies before and my test result showed they have similar performance.  Maybe not correct, but definitely faster than your current implementation.

Answer (score -3):

Yoy can do it by hbase shell by executing following command

```
hbase(main):002:0> count 'consumer-data'
```

Comment: I need to do the count WITH the filter. The count method doesn't support filters, only the scan method does.